# Browser specific functions giving compile errors with SASS

Tags: css, .net, sass

I've got a set of social media icons that I'd like to display on the left side of the screen in a fixed position. I got this working properly, and it works on all browsers except for Firefox. I did some sleuthing, and found that the function I was using (calc(50%-64px)), had browser specific versions. So I've tried to add these to my SCSS file, but I'm getting sass compiler errors, saying my syntax is wrong.

This is an example of a class that is throwing an error. The error doesn't mention anything specific, just that it's a syntax error. It's definitely the browser specific functions, as when I remove them, everything compiles fine.

Am I missing something? I'm fairly new to SASS. I've done tons of digging and can't find a solution.

```
.linkedIcon {
    @include icon($socialIcon);
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    /* Firefox */
    top: -moz-calc(50% - 64px);
    /* WebKit */
    top: -webkit-calc(50% - 64px);
    /* Opera */
    top: -o-calc(50% - 64px);
    /* Standard */
    top: calc(50% - 64px);
    background-image: url('icons/64/linkedIcon.png');
}
```

I'm receiving the following error when compiling *(from comments)*

> An exception was thrown when compiling \SiteStyle.scss:
>   System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException
>   (0x80004005): Invalid access to memory location

Comment: Assuming the `icon` mixin is actually declared somewhere, I cannot reproduce:  http://sassmeister.com/gist/5ca48edb41917c0a4871

Comment: So weird. Not the mixin, as I removed it and still have problems compiling. This is the error: 26/11/2014 10:53:59 AM: An exception was thrown when compiling \SiteStyle.scss: System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException (0x80004005): Invalid access to memory location

Comment: That's not a Sass error.  Unfortunately, I cannot help you further.  `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException` appears to be a Windows/Microsoft specific error.